# Why plot() in R does not reflect data after sorting a dataframe by the values of a column?

Tags: r, plot

This is the complete code:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
require(tidyverse) 
x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/PLOTS/master/drinks_csv.csv")

data <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
data <- data[,c(1:5,8)]


interest <- c(1,2,3,7,9,10,11,14,16,17,21,24,26,29,30,31,34,35,36,38,
              39,40,42,44,47,48,49,50,55,57,61,62,63,65,69,70,71,72,
              73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,89,91,92,93,94,
              100,102,103,104,105,106,108,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,
              118,119,121,122,125,126,127,134,141,142,143,144,152,154,
              155,158,159,160,162,169)

data <- data[interest,]
data <- droplevels(data)
data <- data[with(data, order(data$wine_servings)),]
row.names(data) <- 1:nrow(data)


plot(data$country,data$wine_servings,las=2, xlab="", ylab="", xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = 1:length(data$country), labels = data$country, cex.axis = 0.6,las = 2)
```

The x-axis should display the countries in the order of the value of the y axis. Therefore the plot should be increasing in values from left to right. Yet, this is not what I get, resulting in a misleading and incorrect plot.

I presume that even though I relabeled the rows after sorting, it is still using the initial row values...

Comment: You have to sort the factor levels, not the data. Try a quick search on how to do that, I think there is a lot out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you have above:

```
head(data$country)
[1] afghanistan bangladesh  india       indonesia   iran        iraq       
90 Levels: afghanistan albania algeria argentina australia ... zimbabwe
```

This is a factor, and when you plot it, it is converted to numeric, and drags along the other levels, for example:

```
plot(head(data$country),rep(1,6))
```

[image]

Your data frame is ok, we can just do:

```
plot(1:nrow(data),data$wine_servings,las=2, xlab="", ylab="", xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = 1:length(data$country), labels = as.character(data$country), cex.axis = 0.6,las = 2)
```

[image]

Long and short, be careful when your column is a factor, because base R plot function easily converts them.

Comment: Thank you... I'll accept tomorrow - give your answer a chance to get exposure... This "artifact" you describe only affects plot(), correct? For instance it wouldn't be necessary to tweak something like cor(data$this, data$that), would it?

Comment: You're welcome. So quick followup, for correlation or modeling, not an issue. Might be an issue when you forget the vector is a factor, and use it to subset matrices, or basically functions that can convert them easily.

Comment: In "This is a factor, and when you plot it, it is converted to numeric", they conversion is in alphabetical order, isn't it?

Comment: They are converted to numeric by their levels in the factor. By default, when you have characters in a data.frame, they are converted to factors and their levels are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: for example, as.numeric(factor(c("a","c","b"))) gives u 1,3,2 but if you specify the levels, as.numeric(factor(c("a","c","b"),levels=c("c","b","a"))) it gives you something else

Comment: One final quick question (probably not worth a separate post)... I have noticed that in `plot(head(data$country),rep(1,6))` the plot shows line segments, as opposed to points, and I can't change it to points, do you know why?

Comment: Yes i was correct. so what happens is that plot.factor() is called in that example, and when you do that, it is the equivalent of doing boxplot(rep(1,6)~head(data$country)). Hence you cannot change pch

Comment: that plot? plot(as.numeric(head(data$country)),rep(1,6)) , but you will not get the labels